# How can i extract data from excel to Android compose

Tags: excel, kotlin, android-compose

"I want to extract data from an excel file containing three names, surnames and age to android compose"

"my main activity"

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            ExcelRehersealTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background
                ) {
                    Deneme()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"my function"

```
@Composable
fun Deneme() {
   
    // my excel files path
    val filePath = "Download/deneme.xlsx"

    //create csvreader object
    val reader = CSVReader(FileReader(filePath))

    //read to csvfile
    val rows = reader.readAll()

    //Add each row to a MutableStateList
    val data = remember { mutableStateListOf<MutableList<String>>() }
    for (row in rows) {
        data.add(row.toMutableList())
    }

    // display Mutablelist
    Column(modifier = Modifier.padding(20.dp)) {
        data.forEach { row ->
            Row {
                row.forEach {
                    Text(it)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

"previer code"

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun GreetingPreview() {
    ExcelRehersealTheme {
        Deneme()
    }
}
```

"but it gives me this error 'Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration$ArtifactResolveException: Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.' "